# Unable to send data on my database cant understand what is happening

Tags: php, angular, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Getting this error

> Code:
> Post_providers.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Injectable()
export class PostProviders {
  server: string = "http://localhost/server_api/"

  constructor(public http: Http){
  }

  postData(body, file){

    let type = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
    let headers = new Headers ({'Content-type': type});
    let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});

    return this.http.post(this.server + file, JSON.stringify(body), options)
    .map(res => res.json());
  }
}
```

> file_aksi.php

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Injectable()
export class PostProviders {
  server: string = "http://localhost/server_api/"

  constructor(public http: Http){
  }

  postData(body, file){

    let type = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
    let headers = new Headers ({'Content-type': type});
    let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});

    return this.http.post(this.server + file, JSON.stringify(body), options)
    .map(res => res.json());
  }
}
```

> config.php

```
define('Db_name', 'ionic_app');
define('Db_user', 'root');
define('Db_password', '');
define('Db_host', 'localhost');

$mysqli = new mysqli(Db_name, Db_host, Db_password, Db_user);
```

i have am still trying to solve this issue but still no luck. i am working to solve this error from last 2 days and don't understand that what is the thing which is not correctly done by me.

Error as written in comment by Farrukh iftikhar:

```
core.js:1448 ERROR SyntaxError: 
Unexpected token d in JSON at position 0 
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) 
at Response.Body.json (http.js:1091) 
at MapSubscriber.project (post_providers.ts:20) 
at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:79) 
at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89) 
at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http.js:1591) 
at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3) 
at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4740) 
at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3) at r.runTask (polyfills.js:3)
```

Comment: What's the error that you're getting

Comment: core.js:1448 ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token d in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Response.Body.json (http.js:1091)
    at MapSubscriber.project (post_providers.ts:20)
    at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:79)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http.js:1591)
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4740)
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
    at r.runTask (polyfills.js:3)

Comment: Which version of Angular are you using?

Comment: i am creating an ionic, angular, cordova mobile app and usign php mysql as backend suppporters. ionic verison is: 4.6.1, angular version: 5.2.7

Comment: Okay. Is this code on GitHub? I'd like to have a look at it. Also one last question, what is the version of Rxjs that you're using?

Comment: this code is not on github. the version of rxjs is 4 because i already know that rxjs is changed in the latest update i think it is version 6